# text file of random xml nodes

Tags: c#

i have a snippet of xml that i've pasted in a text file which i would like to parse the value of the name attribute in a console app.

```
    string myXmlString =   

        @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
        <!-- comment at the root level -->
        <Root>
            <data name=""FIELD_ONE"" xml:space=""preserve""> 
                <value>Accompaniment:</value> 
            </data> 
            <data name=""FIELDS_TWO"" xml:space=""preserve""> 
                <value>Accompaniment Detail</value> 
            </data> 
        </Root>";
```

i'd like it to just display the value in my console so i can copy and paste it

Should look like the following:

```
FIELD_ONE
FIELD_TWO
```

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: And what have you tried? You do not expect that we will write code for you, are you?

Comment: i tried the code in the reply below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `XDocument`

Create the `XDocument` with either `XDocument.Load` or `XDocument.Parse` depending if you are loading from a file or a string.

Then to get each of the values you could write.

```
XDocument yourXML = //load it here;

foreach(var element in yourXML.Elements("Root").Elements("data")) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.Attribute("name").ToString());
}
```

Comment: does the xml have to be fully valid, again this is just a snippet of xml that i took from a larger file. i just want to work with this small section.

Comment: i changed my xml above but i get doc.Elements("data") is null

Comment: You probably need to add your namespace to the read. editing.

Comment: Yes if You have a <Root> Element below then you will need to add a `Elements("Root")` before the `Elements("data")`.

Comment: Is there a an easy way to get name and respective value to a dictionary?